# Issues with SHAP plot for model explainability of a NN

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, shap

I built an ANN model and now I'd like to evaluate its feature relevance. For that, I am using the SHAP library.

However, I get a weird Class 0 in my plot even though I don't have any categorical variable. How can I remove this?

Here's the relevant code

```
import shap

# Feature names
features = list(dataset.iloc[:, 0:-1].columns) #dataset is a pandasDataFrame

explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(ann.predict,X_train)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test, nsamples=100)

shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test, feature_names=features)
```

This is the image I get with the Class 0 element:
[image]

I'd also lie to ask, why does my plot does not come out as the traditional SHAP plot? (see image below).
[image]

Comment: Does it work with the command  `shap.plots.beeswarm(shap_values)` ?

Comment: that gives the error: local variable 'values' referenced before assignment

Comment: This works for me with xgboost: 

`explainer = shap.Explainer(clf)`
`shap_values = explainer(X_test)`

`shap.plots.beeswarm(shap_values)`

Comment: yeah this one worked! Thanks.

Comment: Any idea on how to plot the features for this one? Not clear in the documentation...